# Compiling MariaDB server for debugging with ASCII character set

Tags: debugging, plugins, mariadb, charset

My current project revolves around developing unique plugins for MariaDB. This necessitates the use of MariaDB's debugging mode, particularly the 10.5.19 version. I utilize a specific SQL script for my plugins, which demands the ASCII charset.

In the standard use of MariaDB 10.5.19, executing the "show character set;" command reveals the presence of this ASCII charset. However, this charset seems to disappear when I engage the debug version, post-compilation.

The compilation of the debug binary was performed using the script at ./BUILD/compiling-pentium64-debug. This anomaly with the ASCII charset during debugging is a roadblock I'm currently trying to overcome.

Do you have ideas about how to solve this problem?

Without debugging options

Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 3
Server version: 10.5.19-MariaDB-1:10.5.19+maria~ubu2004 mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> show character set;
+----------+-----------------------------+---------------------+--------+
| Charset  | Description                 | Default collation   | Maxlen |
+----------+-----------------------------+---------------------+--------+
| big5     | Big5 Traditional Chinese    | big5_chinese_ci     |      2 |
| dec8     | DEC West European           | dec8_swedish_ci     |      1 |
| cp850    | DOS West European           | cp850_general_ci    |      1 |
| hp8      | HP West European            | hp8_english_ci      |      1 |
| koi8r    | KOI8-R Relcom Russian       | koi8r_general_ci    |      1 |
| latin1   | cp1252 West European        | latin1_swedish_ci   |      1 |
| latin2   | ISO 8859-2 Central European | latin2_general_ci   |      1 |
| swe7     | 7bit Swedish                | swe7_swedish_ci     |      1 |
| ascii    | US ASCII                    | ascii_general_ci    |      1 |
| ujis     | EUC-JP Japanese             | ujis_japanese_ci    |      3 |
| sjis     | Shift-JIS Japanese          | sjis_japanese_ci    |      2 |
| hebrew   | ISO 8859-8 Hebrew           | hebrew_general_ci   |      1 |
| tis620   | TIS620 Thai                 | tis620_thai_ci      |      1 |
| euckr    | EUC-KR Korean               | euckr_korean_ci     |      2 |
| koi8u    | KOI8-U Ukrainian            | koi8u_general_ci    |      1 |
| gb2312   | GB2312 Simplified Chinese   | gb2312_chinese_ci   |      2 |
| greek    | ISO 8859-7 Greek            | greek_general_ci    |      1 |
| cp1250   | Windows Central European    | cp1250_general_ci   |      1 |
| gbk      | GBK Simplified Chinese      | gbk_chinese_ci      |      2 |
| latin5   | ISO 8859-9 Turkish          | latin5_turkish_ci   |      1 |
| armscii8 | ARMSCII-8 Armenian          | armscii8_general_ci |      1 |
| utf8     | UTF-8 Unicode               | utf8_general_ci     |      3 |
| ucs2     | UCS-2 Unicode               | ucs2_general_ci     |      2 |
| cp866    | DOS Russian                 | cp866_general_ci    |      1 |
| keybcs2  | DOS Kamenicky Czech-Slovak  | keybcs2_general_ci  |      1 |
| macce    | Mac Central European        | macce_general_ci    |      1 |
| macroman | Mac West European           | macroman_general_ci |      1 |
| cp852    | DOS Central European        | cp852_general_ci    |      1 |
| latin7   | ISO 8859-13 Baltic          | latin7_general_ci   |      1 |
| utf8mb4  | UTF-8 Unicode               | utf8mb4_general_ci  |      4 |
| cp1251   | Windows Cyrillic            | cp1251_general_ci   |      1 |
| utf16    | UTF-16 Unicode              | utf16_general_ci    |      4 |
| utf16le  | UTF-16LE Unicode            | utf16le_general_ci  |      4 |
| cp1256   | Windows Arabic              | cp1256_general_ci   |      1 |
| cp1257   | Windows Baltic              | cp1257_general_ci   |      1 |
| utf32    | UTF-32 Unicode              | utf32_general_ci    |      4 |
| binary   | Binary pseudo charset       | binary              |      1 |
| geostd8  | GEOSTD8 Georgian            | geostd8_general_ci  |      1 |
| cp932    | SJIS for Windows Japanese   | cp932_japanese_ci   |      2 |
| eucjpms  | UJIS for Windows Japanese   | eucjpms_japanese_ci |      3 |
+----------+-----------------------------+---------------------+--------+

With debugging options

Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 3
Server version: 10.5.19-MariaDB-debug Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> show character set;
+---------+------------------+---------------------+--------+
| Charset | Description      | Default collation   | Maxlen |
+---------+------------------+---------------------+--------+
| big5    |                  | big5_chinese_ci     |      2 |
| latin1  |                  | latin1_swedish_ci   |      1 |
| latin2  |                  | latin2_general_ci   |      1 |
| ujis    |                  | ujis_japanese_ci    |      3 |
| sjis    |                  | sjis_japanese_ci    |      2 |
| tis620  |                  | tis620_thai_ci      |      1 |
| euckr   |                  | euckr_korean_ci     |      2 |
| gb2312  |                  | gb2312_chinese_ci   |      2 |
| cp1250  |                  | cp1250_general_ci   |      1 |
| gbk     |                  | gbk_chinese_ci      |      2 |
| utf8    |                  | utf8_general_ci     |      3 |
| ucs2    |                  | ucs2_general_ci     |      2 |
| utf8mb4 | UTF-8 Unicode    | utf8mb4_general_ci  |      4 |
| utf16   | UTF-16 Unicode   | utf16_general_ci    |      4 |
| utf16le | UTF-16LE Unicode | utf16le_general_ci  |      4 |
| utf32   | UTF-32 Unicode   | utf32_general_ci    |      4 |
| binary  |                  | binary              |      1 |
| cp932   |                  | cp932_japanese_ci   |      2 |
| eucjpms |                  | eucjpms_japanese_ci |      3 |
+---------+------------------+---------------------+--------+
19 rows in set (0.003 sec)

Despite experimenting with versions preceding and succeeding the current one, the persistent issue with the debug binary remains unresolved.

Comment: You can use every Ascii characters in any iso-8859-x mode, so the problem doesn't really exist.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use the compile scripts since a decade, but `compile-pentium-debug64` doesn't build a debug version with all features. You could try to build with `compile-pentium64-debug-max` or `compile-pentium64-debug-all`.

However the recommended way is to build with cmake:

```
cd server_dir
mkdir bld
cd bld
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
make -j5
```

Answer (score -1):

I finally solved the problem. I used the following script and then I saw what the options were for building MariaDB. I determined these options by examining the configure.pl file inside this script, "./configure", which is located in the MariaDB server.

So, ultimately, these commands worked for me.

```
./configure --with-debug --extra-charsets=all
make
make test
make install
```

I found this script in the mariadb documentation

```
  #!/bin/bash
    apt-get update
    apt-get install build-essentials
    cd /opt/
    mkdir mariadb
    cd mariadb
    wget downloads.askmonty.org/f/mariadb-5.3.3-rc/kvm-tarbake-jaunty-x86/mariadb-5.3.3-rc.tar.gz/from/http:/ftp.osuosl.org/pub/mariadb
    mv mariadb mariadb-5.3.3-rc.tar.gz
    tar -xzf mariadb-5.3.3-rc.tar.gz
    ln -s mariadb-5.3.3-rc latest
    cd latest
    mkdir /usr/local/mysql
    mkdir /var/run/mysqld
    groupadd mysql
    useradd -d /usr/local/mysql -s /bin/false -g mysql
    chown mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql
    chown mysql:root /var/run/mysqld
    apt-get install libncurses5-dev
    ./configure --disable-distribution --enable-assembler --with-gnu-ld --with-charset=utf8 --with-extra-charsets=none --without-uca --with-pthread --with-mysqld-user=mysql --with-fast-mutexes --with-atomic-ops=smp --with-big-tables --with-libevent=yes --with-mysqlmanager=no --without-man --with-plugins=max-no-ndb --prefix=/usr/local/mysql
    make
    make test
    make install
    chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql
    /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_install_db --user=mysql
    /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql &
    /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root
```

Comment: In your question you use MariaDB 10.5, in your answer you downgraded to MariaDB 5.3 which reached end of life more than six years ago. Not really a solution.

Comment: I use MariaDB 10.5 i didn't dowgrade also I did not use the entire script, i just used this part:
./configure --with-debug --extra-charsets=all
make
make test
make install

Comment: Those configure perl wrappers were meant as temporary solution for hard-core autotools users,  who were unwilling to learn cmake. That was almost 15 years ago. Today, there might be a single guy remaining who uses the BUILD directory scripts. If you like to be more mainstream, you'd need to build like everyone else does.